# How to chainload from usermode?

Tags: linux, boot, dual-boot

Starting from user mode runlevel in linux, is it possible to boot another OS on the system without ever passing through BIOS or GRUB/similar and never turning off?

Comment: From what operating system?

Comment: @Gilles Linux, hopefully a general solution for most distros, but arch linux if specificity is needed.

Comment: I expect this to be distribution-independent, somewhat dependent on the init system, but definitely very dependent on the kernel. So Linux kernel then.

Comment: You can run a linux kernel from a linux kernel using kexec.  I don't know of any way to chain load another operating system.  That would require a fair amount of dedicated kernel code, and there might not be enough information around to reset all devices and such to the appropriate state such that BIOS calls will work.